# Removing Ubuntu and Installing CentOS

Tags: 13.10, windows, removing

I currently have a dual boot Acer laptop running Windows 8 and Ubuntu.
I want to remove Ubuntu 13.10 and install CentOS on that partition instead.
What's the safest and best way to remove it? I still want to keep my Windows 8.
Will Grub be automatically working after I install CentOS?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have never used CentOS but still best way will be:

Boot from a Bootable disk of CentOS and while installing CentOS

1.First delete all the ubuntu partitions(**This will delete all your ubuntu data**)

***Generally all ubuntu partitions are of `ext4` type and windows partitions are of NTFS type***

*So don't delete windows partitions !*

2.And once you delete ubuntu partitions install CentOS on `Free space`. It will automatically install GRUB for you and will automatically do other things!

Hope this helps!

Comment: Worked! And GRUB automatically installed. Thanks too for the heads up on the ext4!